# angular2 http post request get a error

Tags: http, angular

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/adminUser/login. Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

> error_handler.js:48 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null

server has supported CORS...but I still get this.

the code

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import { getUserApi } from "../../../api.config";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  login(userName, password) {
    return this.http.post(getUserApi, {userName: userName, password:password})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `getUserApi` is null or undefined

Comment: I am sure `getUserApi ` is not null. because I console.log it

Comment: Where you log it?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/adminUser/login. Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score 1):

The header of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' should be in the server response headers not in the request header.